# Why can't I choose FinderSyncAPIExtention

Tags: macos, google-drive

GoogleDrive was stuck in an "Unable to connect" state for a long time, so I decided to re-install it.

However, after re-installation and starting it up for the first time, I see a dialogue asking `Where is FinderSyncAPIExtension?`. I was able to find this in the app Contents folder, but the Finder won't let me select it, it's greyed out.

I'm also unable to select `FinderSyncAPIExtension.appex`.

What am I suppose to do here?

[image: Where is FinderSyncAPIExtension]

Answer (score 0):

It works if you select “Google Drive” directly instead of `Google Drive.app/Contents/PlugIns/FinderSyncAPIExtension.appex`. For more information and discussion [see the question and answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/250793/2392).